# Como obter URL absoluta do meu site

Tags: php, url

Em meu site no arquivo de configuração (config.php) eu utilizo uma constante definida como HOME que contêm o endereço completo do meu site (http://www.meusite.com.br). Utilizo esta constante em include, require e para chamar arquivos css e js. O problema foi quando enviei os arquivos do meu site para o servidor de hospedagem. Por segurança o parâmetro allow_url_include esta desativado, impossibilitando o uso de URLs como constante em meu código.

A minha dúvida esta em qual alternativa usar neste caso para que eu possa obter uma URL absoluta(diretório Root) do meu site e fazer uso da mesma forma que fazia antes?

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` não resolve?

Comment: Acho que está fazendo errado pois o certo seria incluir os arquivos pelo caminho físico. Vide comentário do @stderr